# Multiphase buck converter current waveforms

Tags: dc-dc-converter, simulation, current-measurement, synchronous

I am a student of electrical and computer engineering and am currently working on a project that involves the study of a multiphase buck converter or synchronous buck converter. In simulating the circuit, I noticed that the inductors do not have the same mean current value. It's probably worth mention that MOSFET1 and MOSFET3 also have different current maximum values.

To simulate the circuit, I used PLECS with ideal components.

This is the circuit diagram, the waveform of the inductor currents (IL1 and IL2) and the waveforms of the MOSFET (FETD1 and FETD3) currents.

[image: circuito]

[image: correntes1]

[image: correntes2]

The output current value (Io) is the sum of the currents of the inductors (IL1 and IL2) which is 6 A, as expected, but I don't understand why one inductor carries more current than another.

Why does one inductor carry more current?

Comment: Maybe try a little bit of series resistance (0.05 ohms) in each inductor to see if the two inductor current waveforms eventually converge.

Comment: This [paper](https://www.mdpi.com/2032-6653/13/5/88) explores current mismatches in a multi-phase buck converter. It usually comes from asymmetrical parasitics and uneven voltage drops but you are supposedly using perfect elements in PLECS. Have a look at my free [templates](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/Book/Christophe%20Basso%20SIMPLIS%20Collection.pdf), there is a 2-phase buck in VM and CM and it works with the free demo version of SIMPLIS. Check the voltages at both 1/2 bridges and confirm the left side of each inductor swings to the same values during on- and off-times.

Comment: Having 0 ohm inductors will contribute to this.  I see the MOSFETs must have resistance that (I think) will lower the voltage across the higher current inductor and in time, help balance out the mismatch.  I mostly use Current Mode PWMs that watch the MOSFET's current, and they will adjust the duty cycle to get the current very close to a match.

Comment: @Andyaka I previously used the resistors in series with the inductances and it didn't work well because I must have had some error in the calculations, I remade everything without the resistors and the problem arose. But I just put the resistors back in and it worked. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

From comments

> Maybe try a little bit of series resistance (0.05 ohms) in each
> inductor to see if the two inductor current waveforms eventually
> converge.

> *I just put the resistors back in and it worked. Thank you very much
> for your help. –  José Alves*

I thought so. You are initiating one inductor before the other and it will naturally take a current value that is higher than the 2nd inductor because, it will have done more work in initially charging the output capacitor. In real-life this will settle down due to the ESRs of the inductors but, with ideal inductors and switches this cannot happen.